# Sendmail and Postdrop flooding my server

Tags: linux

I'm out of ideas. Could someone enlighten me?

`ps -ef` shows me.

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f root
/usr/sbin/postdrop -r
```

Does anybody know what is the cause of this?

Comment: Looks like you may have a cronjob failing frequently. Check the mailbox for root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run (on a debian-like system) `apt-file search /usr/sbin/sendmail` or `apt-file search /usr/sbin/postdrop` then you'll probably get the following result:

```bash
# apt-file search /usr/sbin/postdrop
postfix: /usr/sbin/postdrop
```

Which means that the file was installed by the `postfix` package.

You can remove it (if you are sure you don't need it) with:

```bash
sudo apt remove postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system seems to use Postfix for mail delivery.
`/usr/sbin/sendmail` will invoked by *CronDaemon* for cron job generate standard output or standard error out, and `postdrop` will write local mailbox of someone.

Confirm which cron job entry will produce *stdout*/*stderr* for checking cron log or check mailbox */var/spoool/mail*.

FYI: postdrop manual page
http://www.postfix.org/postdrop.1.html